# Get code from TFS with nant

Tags: tfs, nant

I want to take latest source from the Team Foundation Source control project directory to my local machine directory using NAnt build script. 
for that i have used:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="TFUse_GetFiles" default="GetTFSFiles">
 <target name="GetTFSFiles" >
  <exec program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe">
    <arg value="get" />
    <arg value="/login:Domain name\loginid,password" />
    <arg value="$/Projects/dir/Main" />
<arg value="/force" />
  </exec>
 </target> 

</project>
```

the result is showing as [exec]All files are up to date , but no files are copied to my local folder..

So please help me about this probleam if any body has done above mentioned task before.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The TFS client will only download files that are out of date according to the TFS server: it knows previous what gets have taken place to the workspace.

You could use the `/force` option on `tf get` to get everything whatever the server has recorded.

Comment: before check out the code from the TFS we have to map the folder where the code to be stored for which the code is.... <target name="mapping" depends="Workspace" > <exec program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF"> <arg value="workspaces" /> </exec> <exec program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\tf" commandline="workfold /map &quot;$/codepath&quot; C:\localpath /server:servername /workspace:workspacename;loginid /login:login ID,Password" workingdir="."/> </target>

Answer (score 1):

It's like Richard says, in addition: if your `$/Projects/dir/Main` is not a valid source path, TF.exe again replies with "All files are up to date".

You can find the valid path by navigating within source control explorer to the target path & then checking the 'Source location' entry.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `/recursive` as an argument solved my problem of NAnt returning "All files are up to date" even though there were in fact new and updated files to get.